# Functional test in Symfony 3.3 with fake user

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.3

I wanna test my application created in Symfony 3.3.2.
I'm using [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) as my users system.

I create a new client in setUp

```
public function setUp() {
    $this->client = static::createClient();
}
```

I wrote a simple function that should create fake user by fos service

```
private function logInAdmin() {
    $fosLoginManager = $this->client->getContainer()->get('fos_user.security.login_manager');

    $user = new User();
    $user->setEnabled(true);
    $user->addRole('ROLE_ADMIN');

    $fosLoginManager->logInUser('main', $user);
}
```

Actually this is happening but only when I testing this code manually in controller. In this case I'm logged as user whose I just created in code. I have my roles etc. But when PHPUnit run this code, the user becomes `null`.

Why this is happening? How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <?php


namespace AdminBundle\Security;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class LoginTest extends WebTestCase
{

    /**
     * @var Client
     */
    private $client = null;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient();


    }
    private function logIn()
    {
        $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

        // the firewall context defaults to the firewall name
        $firewallContext = 'main';

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('admin', null, $firewallContext, array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
        $session->set('_security_'.$firewallContext, serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    }

    public function testLoginToBackOffice()
    {
        $this->logIn();
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/admin');
        $response = $this->client->getResponse();
        $this->assertSame(Response::HTTP_OK, $response->getStatusCode());
        //200 means i am logged in else should be a redirection to the login path
    }


}
```

I use for my tests sqlite3 as database layer,here is what i put in my config_test.yml

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver: pdo_sqlite
    path:     "%kernel.cache_dir%/db"
    charset: UTF8
```

And before running functionnals tests, i build a db with the schema and some fixtures.

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force --env=test
php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test
php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --env=test
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test -n
```

Inside the fixture i create an admin user.

I just did this now the test is passed.